# Adjusting the width of an segment of a SegmentController

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I need to adjust the width of each segment in a Segment Controller.

I tried;

```
segment.apportionsSegmentWidthsByContent = YES;
```

and it Worked ! But this supports only iOS 5, i need my app to support iOS 4 too. SO what is the iOS 4 equivalent of `apportionsSegmentWidthsByContent` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe it can do it automatically; you'll need to measure out the correct widths, and call setWidth:forSegmentAtIndex: on each segment, based on the amount of text in the control:

> http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UISegmentedControl_Class/Reference/UISegmentedControl.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UISegmentedControl/setWidth:forSegmentAtIndex:

Comment: What arguments are you handing to `setWidth:forSegmentAtIndex:`?  If you call `widthForSegmentAtIndex:`, does it return your new value?

Comment: I don't want to hijack Fletch' answer but try: [segment setWidth:45 forSegmentAtIndex:0];
    [segment setWidth:15 forSegmentAtIndex:1];

Comment: Yes, i tried this before, it didn't work. Well, i tried this in the iOS 5 stimulator and not the iOS 4 stimulator. Will this make any difference ?

Answer (score 1):

You can make the segments autosized to their content. 
So, if necessary use a transparent png in your segment icon content to force a specific width.

Even better, see Fletch' answer above. doh.

Comment: Isn't there any other way i could do this? like isn't there a function like in iOS 5 that i could call instead ? `setWidth:forSegmentAtIndex:` also doesn't work.

Comment: I put an example in a comment to Fletch' answer above.